# How to exit from emergency mode?

Tags: boot

My debian server went to an aborted shutdown and it goes to an emergency mode. How can I make it back to normal boot option.

Comment: SHOUTING won't help.

Comment: okay.whats the way to boot in normal mode

Comment: Don't break your system. Now, fix your title.

Comment: What do you mean by "aborted shutdown"? What do you mean by "emergency mode"? What is the EXACT message shown on the screen that you have to respond to? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You end up in Emergency Mode **for a reason**. Something is obviously wrong with your system. Whilst in Emergency Mode, enter the `root` password and try to diagnose what is causing this.

After fixing those issues, your system will be able to boot properly again.

In other words, there is no "quick fix" for this. Do the usual digging (`dmesg`, `journalctl` etc...) and try to rectify the problems!